# Multiple screens in manifest and compatibility mode confusion

Tags: android, layout, screen, manifest, compatibility-mode

I read this somewhere and I am little confused

"if your application explicitly supports those screens ( true) or
requires "compatibility mode" assistance ( false)."

it is about the supports-screens in manifest

```
<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="false"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="false"
android:anyDensity="true"
/>
```

I far as understood if I say I do not want to support large and small screen my application will be still available on the market for phones with large and small screen and also the app will be able to be run on such devices. Only the screen will be draw according the compatibility mode... Did I get it right ?

well I expected that if I sat I do not support small screen I do not want my app to be able to be install on device with small screen...

How can I prohibit the installation on devices with small screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Market filters will help you to prevent Market visibility for devices with small screens. Have a look at `<compatible-screens>`.
You can find more information at the bottom of this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

Comment: but it is not just the market, how can I prevent the app from installing on device with small screen

Comment: I don't think you can prevent installation. All compatibility checks happen in the market. If the user manages to get the APK from another source he might install it, no matter what's declared inside the manifest. But you could check screen sizes when starting the app and terminate it (with a meaningful message) if it's a small screen device.